# How to create a event source system with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, events, cqrs, event-sourcing, event-driven-design

I am quite new to event source concept but got glimpse that i need to divide my each task or operation to event and save those, but my basic do but is if for each request if you save each step as event then should not be the db size increase and large in short time also how to read it properly.

I just like to know if there any any blog or article or example that you guys could provide for reference and answer the above concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are doing that for learning or for a real project, but in both cases I would suggest you to have a look at https://www.eventstore.com.
It is a db modeled to do event sourcing, also if not using it studying how it works will tell you what things you need to have in order to do it